# Problems with returning ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I added Strings `"Hello"`, `"Cat"`, `"Dog"` into the arraylist called `values` passed it to the method `doubleIt()` which should return a list of everything doubled, i.e.

```
"Hello", "Hello", "Cat", "Cat", "Dog", "Dog"
```

But all Im getting is `[]`. What could I do wrong here ?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Addition
{

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
        values.add("Hello");
        values.add("Cat");
        values.add("Dog");

        values = doubleIt(values);
        System.out.println(values);

    }

    public static List<String> doubleIt(List<String> values)
    {
        List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++)
        {
            temp.add(values.get(i*2));
        }
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of `temp.add(values.get(i*2));` you should use `temp.add(values.get(i));temp.add(values.get(i));` and `temp.size()` replace with `values.size()`

Comment: What is the size of `temp` when you start looping?

Comment: Or simply `temp.addAll(values);` twice...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first mistake is here...

```
for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++)
```

`temp.size()` will be `0` when it's called the first time, you really should be using a `values`, but this will cause an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

So you could use something like...

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) {
    temp.add(values.get(i));
    temp.add(values.get(i));
}
```

instead

Answer (score 1):

First change your for loop condition from

```
for(int i = 0; i < temp.size(); i++)
```

to

```
for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)
```

and then add values 2 times each.

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop in `doubleIt()` was looping up to the wrong list size. And you were trying to multiply a string by 2, instead of adding it twice.

```
public static List<String> doubleIt(List<String> values)
{
    List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();

    for(int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++) // <-- you needed to loop up to the size of the values list, not the temp list
    {
        temp.add(values.get(i));
        temp.add(values.get(i));
    }
    return temp;
}
```